# Extend Application function every time i want to use Koin injection in Ktor?

Tags: ktor, koin

I would like to pull some data from url in Ktor. In order to use Koin injection i need to create my `fetch()` as an extension of `Application`. Is this the recommended way to write injectable functions in Ktor? To me it seems code smelly to have every injectable function as an extension of `Application`. Or is this totally fine?

```
suspend fun Application.fetch(): Map<String, FetchResult> {
    val client: HttpServiceImpl by inject()
    return client.getClient().get("some_url")
        .body<Map<String, FetchResult>>()
}
```